# fn_LShortNameToLCID in SQL Database

Tags: sql-server, ssrs

My question sound stupid but i didn't understand and searching on google didn't helped either.

I have a SQL query which i use in SCCM Reporting.
I just want to say that my hands are bit tight in SQL and database related stuffs.
Below is the SQL query.

```
   SELECT top 3 *
 FROM fn_appdtclientsummarizedstate(dbo.fn_LShortNameToLCID(1033)) acs
```

This is, i get from existing report (SSRS).

I checked the SCCM database but this table, views is not there. Hence i can't make the modifications as needed.

If you can help me then i would be very grateful.

I spent almost 2 days but no luck finding/understanding this query.

Comment: how about you look for `select * from sys.objects where name like 'fn_appdtclient%'` ? Looks like function based on how it is named.

Comment: @KinShah Let me try, Is there any way to edit that function. Update: I just ran your query and found one matching record. SQL_INLINE_TABLE_VALUED_FUNCTION

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should install [SQL Search](https://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-search)

I think you will find it as a 'Table-valued function'  (a function that returns a table )